# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera HMS Huawei P40 plus

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am working in a app who works in gms(google services) and hms (huawei services), for this i have the HMS tool instaled on My android studio and typically the app works fine in both systems, but with a cellphone in specific the app crashes , the log fail is: *Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera*

It seems the cellphone can't find the HMS Core

Have any body a clue for this fail?

Comment: hi@Marcela Dueñas, Can you share the stack trace or full logs of the error you're having, so we can help you properly?

Comment: The error suggests its trying to find GMS not HMS. but as @shirley mentioned, please include the full error log and an example of how you are using both GMS and HMS together.

Comment: I have no idea what is the issue finnaly , when i try to get the log again, the app begin to work , some body told me the issue was in the emiu 12+ phones. How ever i'll like to know what happened